Mongodb sparse index vs partial index
I have a large collection of documents that have field C = null about 85% of the time and have queries looking for docs where C $ne: null.  To speed those queries, I have considered a sparse and a partial index.
Sparse:
db.collection.createIndex(
{A: 1, B: 1, C: 1},
{sparse: true, name:"sparse_A_B_C" }
);

Partial:
db.collection.createIndex(
{ A: 1, B: 1 },
{ partialFilterExpression: { C: $exists: true} }, name: "partial_A_B_C"}
);

Both indexes seem to me to be effectively identical and both are created fine. The optimizer will ignore the sparse index and use the partial one to good effect.  Even if I drop the partial index, the optimizer will ignore the sparse index, prefering to use a full index on A, B with a slower result. (And yes, I've cleared the planCache.)
So this is not really a problem.  I can certainly just continue to use the partial.  But I'm curious about the similarities/diffs in the indexes.  Can anyone help me understand this?  Is this expected behavior?  Are the indexes not really effectively the same?  Am I missing something?

See documentation: "MongoDB provides the option to create partial indexes. Partial indexes offer a superset of the functionality of sparse indexes. Partial Indexes should be preferred over sparse indexes." Just use partial indexes and don't waste your time.
